# CEF Folder inside Application Support - Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos

I deleted this folder a few days ago and it came back recently. Inside there are two empty sub folders (User Data and Dictionaries). I'm running Yosemite.

Not sure what app or where these folders are coming from. I've heard it's from Google Chrome/Widevine CDM but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: CEF is [Chromium Embedded Framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework) it's related to Chrome, but isn't Chrome. It's embedded in a lot of apps, so figuring out which might not be easy.